# MSBUILD takes way too long to transfer files to FTP site

Tags: msbuild, ftp, automation

Been attempting to automate FTP transfers using MSBUILD community packs via CruiseControl. The data is just over a gig. It was taking 3 hours and still didn't finish the transfer! I had to kill it because it was taking so long. Any ideas on how to make this faster? I know it can go faster because FileZilla can transfer the whole thing in 45 minutes!

Here's the script:

```
<Target Name="FTPDeployTransfer">
    <FtpUploadDirectoryContent
  ServerHost="$(ftpHost)"
  Port="$(ftpPort)"
  Username="$(ftpUser)"
  Password="$(ftpPass)"
  LocalDirectory="Path to local"
  RemoteDirectory="path to remote directory"
  Recursive="true"
        />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Can you post your build script or part where you trying to copy files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written that you used MSBuild community packs: was it [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks)  or [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/).

In MSBuild Extension Pack you can try FTP Task that handles uploading of files to FTP server.

If it is the task that you tried or this doesn't help you - it's possible to execute FileZilla from MSBuild via Exec Task so it handle transfer to FTP.

[**EDIT**]

Yes, you can also try WinSCP for FTP transfer take a look at this article: [MSBuild and WinSCP](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/09/21/continuous-integration-tip-1-ndash-ftp-deployment).

You can find [ideas on how to speed up your transfer](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_slow).

Comment: I used MSBuild community tasks. I dont think this is good for large data. Can I really automate FileZilla? I heard that it doesn't support automation. I was thinking about WinSCP though. Do you know if that is just as fast as FileZilla?

Comment: I have edited my answer, but encourage you to try out MSBuild extension pack it easy to understand and helped me a lot in past

Comment: I've used winscp and that really solved all my problems. Now all I need to do is somehow setup an automated email response whenever the transfer is completed or aborted. But that's another problem!